# In "Отец не имеет прав на ребёнка", is ребёнка in accusative or genitive case?

Tags: падежи

My guess is accusative case due to *на*, but I'm wondering if the negation (from **не иметь**) affects *ребёнок* here, as it does *право*.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is accusative case due to "на".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предыдущий ответ вообще-то неправильный.
Не так важно, что прав или права нет, важно что бывает право (или права) НА (кого/что) управление, проход, ребенка, жизнь...
или просто право (права) (кого/чего) сильного, человека, прохода, управления.